# DefinePInvokeMethod -- Marshal System.String to std::string

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, reflection.emit

I'm looking for flexible ways to write my own DLL's and access DLL's that are handled to me in C++ using C++/CLI.  I'm pretty new to InterOp and Reflection, and it seems especially that marshaling StringBuilder to a DLL function that takes an entry point with parameter char* (helloc in the code) is effective when using DefinePInvokeMethod.   IJW takes care of the case where the entry point takes a std::string in a direct call to the dll, but why are there TargetInvocationExceptions when I also try to marshal a StringBuilder to std::string using DefinePInvokeMethod.   Why does the IJW facility not know to construct a std::string in this case? Isn't the callee responsible for constructing the string on the unmanaged side?  Below is the working code.   Would someone please help me through its adaptation such that hellos(std::string) can also be accessed via DefinePInvokeMethod?

**native.dll**

```
//Both methods just std::cout << greeting;
extern "C" DLL void helloc(char* greeting);
extern "C" DLL void hellos(std::string greeting)
```

**Test.cpp**

```
void pinvoketest()
{
// Create the AssemblyBuilder.
AssemblyName^ asmName = gcnew AssemblyName("PInvokeTest");
AssemblyBuilder^ dynamicAsm = AppDomain::CurrentDomain->DefineDynamicAssembly(
    asmName,
    AssemblyBuilderAccess::RunAndSave
);

// Create the module.
ModuleBuilder^ dynamicMod =
    dynamicAsm->DefineDynamicModule(asmName->Name, asmName->Name + ".dll");

TypeBuilder^ tb = dynamicMod->DefineType(
    "MyType",
    TypeAttributes::Public | TypeAttributes::UnicodeClass
);
MethodInfo^ mi;
try
{
    MethodBuilder^ mb = tb->DefinePInvokeMethod(
        "helloc",
        "native.dll",
        "helloc",
        MethodAttributes::Public | MethodAttributes::Static | MethodAttributes::PinvokeImpl,
        CallingConventions::Standard,
        void::typeid,
        gcnew array<Type^>{StringBuilder::typeid},
        CallingConvention::Cdecl,
        CharSet::Ansi);

mb->SetImplementationFlags(
mb->GetMethodImplementationFlags() | MethodImplAttributes::PreserveSig);


Type^ t = tb->CreateType();


mi = t->GetMethod("helloc");

Console::WriteLine("Testing PInvoke method...");
mi->Invoke(nullptr, gcnew array<Object^>{gcnew StringBuilder("This is a test greeting")});

char x;
std::cin >> x;
}
catch (TargetInvocationException^ ex)
{
    Console::WriteLine(ex->InnerException);
    char x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
catch (Exception^ ex)
{

    Console::WriteLine(ex);
    char x;
    std::cin >> x;

}
};
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've seen them all before...  None of them help me call a native DLL with DefinePInvokeMethod against an entry point that takes std::string

Comment: You cannot pinvoke a C++ function that takes C++ class objects like std::string as arguments. Pinvoke only supports C language types. It is not a problem with C++ Interop (aka IJW) but that is not what you seem to try to do for some reason. If it takes a const std::string&, and assuming the DLL was built with the exact same compiler version using the exact same build settings, then you can hack it with IntPtr.

Comment: Thank you Hans.   I'll hack around with std::string& just to try it out.